# How can I specify if the Android library/module I created should be the launcher Activity?

Tags: android, android-library

I'm trying to create an Android Library using the wizard.

I choose new > module > Phone & Tablet Module > Choose names > Adding a Blank Activity with Fragment. Then I name my activity and it doesn't anywhere let me specify if I want this to be the launcher activity or not. Seems to be making it the launcher activity by default.

Then I change the **apply plugin: 'com.android.Application'** to **apply plugin: 'com.android.library'** to make this a library, remove the id and the intent-filter that makes it the launcher activity.

My question is: Is this the right way to make and Android Library?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't remember whether it creates launch intent for library. But if it is true why you not want just remove intent declaration in your library manifest file?
Also you can create simple app that will test your library and then add your library module. You can build your library module in jar if you will need it.
P.S. Sorry for my English.